# Dynamic JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'd like to be able to target an HTML element and I've got some PHP / JavaScript like this where `id = 1`:

```
echo 'var my_div_id = "div_" + id;
      var my_div = $( "#my_div_id" );';

<div id="div_1">Div 1</div>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. i.e. I can't target the DIV. Note, when I was targeting it statically (i.e. using `$( "#div_1" )` it would work ok) so the problem is arising when I dynamically target it.

Is it something to do with `my_div_id` not being interpreted as I'm expecting?

Comment: `"#" + my_div_id`

Comment: is your *my_div_id* is generated properly?

Comment: Doh - yes, fixed in question

Comment: id is php variable or javascript variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using  $( '#' + my_div_id )

```
 echo "var my_div_id = "div_" + id;
       var my_div = $( '#' + my_div_id );";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to find an element with jQuery befor the element exists on the DOM.

Split your echos:

```
echo 'var my_div_id = "div_"'.id;
?><div "#div_1">Div 1</div><?php
echo 'var my_div = $( "#my_div_id" );';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try. Your id variable should be appended like `var my_div_id = 'div_' + id;` and my_div_id variable should be appended in selector like `var my_div = $( '#' + my_div_id );`

```
echo "var my_div_id = 'div_' + id;
      var my_div = $( '#' + my_div_id );";
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$result = 'var my_div_id = "div_"'+ id;
$result += 'var my_div = $( "#my_div_id" );';
echo $result;
```